# Rails js.erb not executing javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a search form in my rails app using simple_form.

Code in my view

```
= simple_form_for :principal, url: url_for(action: 'analyze', controller: 'principals', format: :js, dataType: 'script'), method: :get, remote: :true do |f|
  = f.input :category_id, input_html: {name: :category_id }
=f.button :submit
```

Code in analyze.js.erb

```
alert("check");
```

In response tab it is showing me `alert("check");`

but on completion of request it is not showing me alert box.

Comment: Can you show us controller action for `analyze.js.erb` and your controller code please?

Comment: Solved this problem by adding data-type: "script" into the form tag.  = simple_form_for :principal, url: url_for(action: 'analyze', controller: 'principals'), method: :get, html: { data: {type: 'script'},remote: :true} do |f|

Answer (score 1):

Looks like errors in analyze.js.erb. You retrieved the js response, but javascript is not valid.